# Basis polynomial functions

Tags: linear-algebra

If I suppose $R \subset F$ and have polynomial functions $p_{k,j} : F \to F$ by

$p_{1,0}(x)=(x-2)^3$

$p_{2,0}(x)=(x-1)$

$p_{2,1}(x)=(x-1)(x-2)$

$p_{2,2}(x)=(x-1)(x-2)^2$

and the polynomial function $p: F \to F$ given by $p(x)=(x-1)(x-2)^3$.  How would I show that {${p_{1,0}, p_{2,0}, p_{2,1}, p_{2,2}}$} is a basis for polynomial functions from $F$ to $F$ of degree three or less?

Comment: You could show that the span of the standard basis vectors (or basis functions or whatever you want to call them) are a subspace of the span of your basis vectors.  Or use the Gram-Schmidt process to get an orthogonal basis.  If you get $4$ non-zero orthogonal vectors, then your vectors span your space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that there are non-zero $\alpha_0, ..., \alpha_3$ such that

$$\alpha_0p_{1,0} + ... + \alpha_3p_{2,2} = 0$$

Evaluating in x = 1:

$$(\alpha_0p_{1,0}(1) + ... + \alpha_3p_{2,2}(1) = 0 \iff \alpha_0(1-2)^3 = 0 \iff -\alpha_0 = 0) \implies \alpha_0 = 0$$

Now we've got

$$\alpha_1p_{2,0} + ... + \alpha_3p_{2,2} = 0$$

Evaluating in x = 2,

$$(\alpha_1p_{2,0}(2) + ... + \alpha_3p_{2,2}(2) = 0 \iff \alpha_1(2-1) = 0) \implies \alpha_1 = 0$$

Now, we've got

$$\alpha_2p_{2,1} + \alpha_3p_{2,2} = 0$$

Which will yield that $\alpha_2 = 0$ and $\alpha_3 = 0$. Now notice that $\beta = \{p_{1,0}, p_{2,0}, p_{2,1}, p_{2,2}\}$ is a linearly independent sets of vectors such that $dim\beta = 4 = dim \mathbb{K}_3[X]$, thus, $\beta$ is a basis for $\mathbb{K}_3[X]$

Comment: How would I express the polynomial functions $f_0: F \to F$ and $f_1: F \to F$ given by $f_0(x)=1$ and $f_1(x)=x$ in this basis?

Comment: Well, what I would do is use the isomorphism between vector spaces of finite dimension to translate the problem into $\mathbb{R}^4$. For example, I'd convert $x-1$ into $(-1, 1, 0, 0)$, or $3x^2+2x+1$ into $(1, 2, 3, 0)$. In such a way, you could convert the basis $\beta$ into a basis $\beta'$ for $\mathbb{R}^4$, and hence expressing $x$ would be the same as expressing $(0, 1, 0, 0)$. Notice that the coordinates would be the same as long as the vector order in the basis is not changed.